# How to Design complex table using WPF

Tags: xaml

Is it possible to have grid with 2 columns for example, and have different number of rows in each of it, like 4 in first, 3 in second.

[image: Table Example]

I'd like something like on the picture

Comment: This question shows sooo much research, sooo useful, that I had to upvote it! Unfortunately the answer doesn't show the best practices, and rightfully is not accepted! As soon as this site allows me I'm going to offer a bounty here, requiring a detailed canonical answer

Comment: @Ash - What do you mean by "the answer doesn't show the best practices"? The answer is plain XAML, so what best practices do you expect to be shown?

Comment: @SimonMourier, I expect to see a piece of plain xaml which doesn't give a headache to a person maintaining it. E.g. small change - split header in 3 columns (1. fixed width logo, 2. some greetings 3. same logo) will require to modify layout from Sach's answer completely, but it shouldn't.

Comment: @ASh Actually I attached photo for not to speak a lot but show)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't do that with just one `Grid`, but using multiple `Grid` controls, the `ColumnSpan` and `RowSpan` properties, and some sort of a control, you can generate a 'grid' like that.

```
<Window x:Class="SOWPF.MainWindow"
        ...
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Border Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Margin="4" Background="Orange"/>

        <Border Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Margin="4" Background="Green"/>
        <Border Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2" Margin="4" Background="Green"/>
        <Border Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="3" Margin="4" Background="Green"/>
        <Border Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="4" Margin="4" Background="Green"/>

        <Border Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Grid.RowSpan="4" Margin="4" Background="Orchid">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition/>
                    <RowDefinition/>
                    <RowDefinition/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                <Border Grid.Row="0" Margin="4" Background="DeepSkyBlue"/>
                <Border Grid.Row="1" Margin="4" Background="DeepSkyBlue"/>
                <Border Grid.Row="2" Margin="4" Background="DeepSkyBlue"/>
            </Grid>
        </Border>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

The View:

[image]

Comment: I'm designing a SignUp page, and actually, I solved problem using `Grid.RowSpan` and `Grid.ColumnSpan` only, but table's rows/columns wasn't changed.Anyway, your answer helped a lot, thanks!